# How can I remove white spaces between keys and values of object

Tags: javascript, php

I want to remove all the white spaces between the keys, or names of the objects before I decode them using `json_decode` method.

Like `Income cut` can i make it `Income_cut`.

Is there a way around this.

```
{
    "Housing": 0,
    "Late Comers": 0,
    "Income cut": "12500",
    "Study Allowance": 0,
    "test": 0,
    "i": 0,
    "staff_no": "9",
    "staff_name": "Abeja Vicky",
    "staff_department": "Production Staff",
    "staff_position": "Production Manager",
    "staff_salary": "0",
    "GrossValue": 12500,
    "GrossSalary": 0,
    "NSSF": 0,
    "PAYE": 0,
    "GrossValueAddiotion": 0,
    "GrossValueDecuction": 12500,
    "netPay": -12500,
    "Balance": 0,
    "Paidx": 0,
    "balance": -12500
}
```

Comment: You want to replace spaces just in keys or also in values?

Comment: All the solutions so far are processing the data on the client before sending. If you're only seeking a server side PHP solution then that should be specified in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming not nested simple json object ,below will work before sending to server

```
var input ={
    "Housing": 0,
    "Late Comers": 0,
    "Income cut": "12500",
    "Study Allowance": 0,
    "test": 0,
    "i": 0,
    "staff_no": "9",
    "staff_name": "Abeja Vicky",
    "staff_department": "Production Staff",
    "staff_position": "Production Manager",
    "staff_salary": "0",
    "GrossValue": 12500,
    "GrossSalary": 0,
    "NSSF": 0,
    "PAYE": 0,
    "GrossValueAddiotion": 0,
    "GrossValueDecuction": 12500,
    "netPay": -12500,
    "Balance": 0,
    "Paidx": 0,
    "balance": -12500
}

var output = {};
for(var key in input){
  output[key.replace(/\s+/,'_')] = input[key];
}

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do it like this:[Working Example](http://jsbin.com/lefeku/edit?js,console,output)

```
var f={
    "Housing": 0,
    "Late Comers": 0,
    "Income cut": "12500",
    "Study Allowance": 0,
    "test": 0,
    "i": 0,
    "staff_no": "9",
    "staff_name": "Abeja Vicky",
    "staff_department": "Production Staff",
    "staff_position": "Production Manager",
    "staff_salary": "0",
    "GrossValue": 12500,
    "GrossSalary": 0,
    "NSSF": 0,
    "PAYE": 0,
    "GrossValueAddiotion": 0,
    "GrossValueDecuction": 12500,
    "netPay": -12500,
    "Balance": 0,
    "Paidx": 0,  
    "balance": -12500
}; 


function removeWhiteSpace(obj) {
    if (typeof obj !== "object") return obj;
    for (var prop in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            obj[prop.replace(" ", "_")] =  removeWhiteSpace(obj[prop]); 
            if (prop.indexOf(" ") > -1) { 
                delete obj[prop];  
            } 
        }
    }
    return obj;
}


var ob=removeWhiteSpace(f);
```

Comment: Your solution is the only one that produced the correct results in my tests. up voted.

Comment: var new_str = f.replace(" ","","g") I tried that and it remove the white spaces what do you say about it

Answer (score 1):

You could loop through the object attributes and replace any space by underscore `_` :

```
var object_without_spaces ={};
for(var key in o) {
    var value = String(o[key]).replace(/ /g,"_");
    var key = String(key).replace(/ /g,"_");

    object_without_spaces[key]=value;
}

console.log(object_without_spaces);
//Object {Housing: "0", Late_Comers: "0", Income_cut: "12500", Study_Allowance: "0", test…}
```

If you want to remove spaces just in `keys` use :

```
for(var key in o) {
    var new_key = String(key).replace(/ /g,"_");
    object_without_spaces[new_key]=o[key];
}
```

Hope this helps.

---

```js
var o ={
    "Housing": 0,
    "Late Comers": 0,
    "Income cut": "12500",
    "Study Allowance": 0,
    "test": 0,
    "i": 0,
    "staff_no": "9",
    "staff_name": "Abeja Vicky",
    "staff_department": "Production Staff",
    "staff_position": "Production Manager",
    "staff_salary": "0",
    "GrossValue": 12500,
    "GrossSalary": 0,
    "NSSF": 0,
    "PAYE": 0,
    "GrossValueAddiotion": 0,
    "GrossValueDecuction": 12500,
    "netPay": -12500,
    "Balance": 0,
    "Paidx": 0,
    "balance": -12500
}

var object_without_spaces ={};

for(var key in o) {
    var value = String(o[key]).replace(/ /g,"_");
    var key = String(key).replace(/ /g,"_");

    object_without_spaces[key]=value;
}

console.log(object_without_spaces);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Another Alternative**

Some of the posted solutions fail when tested, especially when the input is varied slightly. @itsgoingdown's answer actually works the best (up voted) because it filters before cloning the object.

Regardless, I thought I'd post my answer as an alternative. It uses [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) stringify and parse methods to shallow clone the object. This eliminates having to filter the properties in the for loop. Ideally, one would also want to check for name collisions prior to changing a property name. That has not been done here or in any of the solutions.

**Check Show code and then Run snippet to try.**

```
// Same as JSON.stringify, but replaces whitespace in property names.

function stringify(obj, replacer, space) {
  var key, prop, copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
  for (prop in copy) {
    key = prop.replace(/\W/g, '_');
    if (key != prop) {
      copy[key] = copy[prop];
      delete copy[prop];
    }
  }
  return JSON.stringify(copy, replacer, space);
}
```

```js
// Same as JSON.stringify, but replaces whitespace in property names.

function stringify(obj, replacer, space) {
  var key, prop, copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
  for (prop in copy) {
    key = prop.replace(/\W/g, '_');
    if (key != prop) {
      copy[key] = copy[prop];
      delete copy[prop];
    }
  }
  return JSON.stringify(copy, replacer, space);
}





var data = {
  "test 1": function(a) {
    return 1;
  },
  "test 2": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  "test 3": "Hello World!",
  "Housing": 0,
  "Late Comers": 0,
  "Income cut": "12500",
  "Study Allowance": 0,
  "i": 0,
  "staff_no": "9",
  "staff_name": "Abeja Vicky",
  "staff_department": "Production Staff",
  "staff_position": "Production Manager",
  "staff_salary": "0",
  "GrossValue": 12500,
  "GrossSalary": 0,
  "NSSF": 0,
  "PAYE": 0,
  "GrossValueAddiotion": 0,
  "GrossValueDecuction": 12500,
  "netPay": -12500,
  "Balance": 0,
  "Paidx": 0,
  "balance": -12500
};



document.getElementById('stdout').innerHTML = stringify(data, false, '  ');
```

```html
<xmp id="stdout"></xmp>
```